# Openshift: action_hook "start" is not executed

Tags: openshift

i have a DIY-Application and following problem: the action_hook "start" is not executed anymore and i dont know why.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "STARRRT"
```

My output after git push:

```
> remote: Stopping DIY cartridge remote: CLIENT_RESULT: Application is
> already stopped remote: Building git ref 'master', commit 828e522
> remote: Preparing build for deployment remote: Deployment id is
> 44438b26 remote: Activating deployment remote: Starting DIY cartridge
> remote: ------------------------- remote: Git Post-Receive Result:
> success remote: Activation status: success remote: Deployment
> completed with status: success
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

These are the valid action_hooks (https://www.openshift.com/developers/deploying-and-building-applications) along with some cartridge specific ones like pre_start_ruby etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure the hook has the +x bit set?

I use Windows, and the only way to set the hook with a +X is to either checkout to Cygwin or use the git command `git update-index --chmod=+x <file>`